# Im new to programming in Java and my code wont work. any tips please?

Tags: java, variables, newline, biginteger

Help im new to programming
i want to store a big number(999999999999999999999+) to a variable.
and another big number assigned to another variable.
and i want to devide this two variable to each other.
how do i do it?

i have this code. that wont work.

```
    String a = "9999999999999999999999";
    String b = "99999"

    while(b < a)
    { 
    a / b; 
    c = a / b; 
    c / b;
    a = c / b; 

    }

    if(a <= b)
    {
    System.out.print(a)

    }
```

i created this problem my self and i want this to work but it wont.
can anyone please give me some advice?

Comment: Debugger is there, and for free. Use it.

Comment: You can't divide strings.  You should investigate BigInteger.

Comment: You need to follow a tutorial first. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: You can't divide Strings (words). If it would be possible then what should be result of `"foo"/"bar"`? Same about using `<` operator on Strings, what should be result of `"my cat"<"is happy"`. You need to use proper numeric type like `int` or `long` or maybe even `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Use Javas BigDecimal or BigInteger classes to store your numbers

Answer (score 4):

A `String` object is just text. You can not divide a text by another text - it's an operation which doesn't make sense.

When in `int` isn't large enough, you could use a `long` which is a 64 bit long integer and goes up to `9223372036854775808`.

Another option is to use floating-point math with the types `float`or `double`. They represent a number with an exponent which gives them a huge range. However, floating-point values become less accurate the larger they get, so you might get unexpected inaccuracies ([sometimes even for small values](http://floating-point-gui.de/)).

When you need both huge numbers and arithmetics which are precise to the last digit, you should use the classes [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) or [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) (depending on whether or not you want decimal places). These classes allow you to perform arithmetics with numbers of arbitrary size. 
The drawback is that arithmetics with objects of these classes are much slower than with the native data-types.

Answer (score 0):

Some of these answers make no sense, lol.

You have 2 problems with this code. First, a and b are declared as Strings, and you cannot divide strings (I think? I've never tested that to know, but I highly doubt it)

First, java's Interger variables are 32 bit. In other words, they cannot store more than 9 characters.
So int a is already invalid.

Your options then are to either parse a to an int, or just change them to integers, AFTER YOU FIX int a's value.

Ex for parse.

```
int aInt = Integer.parseInt(a);
int bInt = Integer.parseInt(b);
```

Then use aInt and bInt for your calculations.

Comment: I did state that. "First, java's Integer variables are 32 bit. In other words, they cannot store more than 9 characters. So int a is already invalid"

Comment: You also said it was an option.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have two variables which both of them are String so you can not divide them and you should have seen this error while compiling your app "operator / cannot be applied to java.lang.String,java.lang.String".
I think your approach is to store the number in an array and then dividing them with each other which might be a reasonable solution but there is two notes:

1. As String is an array of character you do not need to define an array(which you've done it correctly)
2. You need to cast those part into integer when you want to divide part of that string with another(It's like a simple math. You do the same thing when you're dividing 10 / 4 on paper).

In conclusion, I would suggest you to checkout BigInt and BigDecimal documentation. They definitely work for you. Also, think about the first solution I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

First, the `c` is not declared.
Second, string is basically text, "hello" etc.
Third, your `a` is very big, so using  `int` won't work, so in order to fix this problem is to use `BigInteger`

Answer (score -2):

You haven't declared the variable `c` You've just stated that `c = a / b` also a/b would work better if you declared them as a `double` rather than a string as you can not divide strings.